# Do we need [hack] and [hacked]?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the [hack](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hack) tag (currently 6 Open questions) *and* the [hacked](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacked) tag (currently 21 Open questions); both without any wikis.

Do we need *both* tags?

Bonus: We also have [security](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) - when should one use one of these together with [security](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)?

Presently [security](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) is used along with tag [hacked](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacked) for 4 Open questions. Its Usage guide is:

> A branch of computer technology known as information security as applied to computers and networks.

Edit: [How to write in super large letters in an ordinary textfield](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47152/how-to-write-in-super-large-letters-in-an-ordinary-textfield) seems to be the only one tagged [hack](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hack) that's *not* about being hacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** The OP has reached 40 views with [nem. con.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nem._con.) and tag [hack](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hack) is now no longer in use, tag [hacked](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacked) has a Usage guide, presently:

> For questions about the consequences of unauthorised access to an account or for recovery procedures / damage limitation where such access has been obtained. Use a tag like [security] or [privacy], as appropriate, for questions about how to prevent unauthorised access.

and there are no Qs (at present) applying both tag [security](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) and tag [hacked](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacked).

---

“hack” in the sense of a workaround is a meta concept and is not appropriate as a tag. The sole Q with such use has other tags and does not require [hack](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hack) which should be removed there and never used again.

“hacked” is a common term for accounts that have been compromised and is a concise and meaningful description of either the owner's complete loss of access to an account or the sharing of access to an account between its true owner and one or more others not authorised by the true owner.

“hacked” in the sense of purloined account is approximately the opposite of tag [security](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) and is as valid a tag as that. “hacked” is a consequence of security that was not of a high enough standard. Being close to antonyms, the two should not normally be applied to the same Q – either the emphasis will be how to *prevent* being hacked (use tag [security](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security)) or how to *recover* from a breach of security (use tag [hacked](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacked)).